# Does the code for Variational Autoencoders essentially stay the same apart from the data set?

Tags: machine-learning, pytorch

When we make a Variational Autoencoder, I want to know if the code(I use PyTorch) essentially stays the same and we just change the Data Set. This was something that always confused me and I wanted to know if someone could clarify this. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Yes, it does.

However:
Different types of data may necessitate different AE architectures, including different latent distributions (look up learned image compression, a large amount of different AE architectures has been proposed).

This question would probably be a better fit to https://stats.stackexchange.com/